# What is the general way to know structures of a class (instance) provided by 3rd party?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am new to Flutter (Dart) and this may be a basic question.

I got my current geolocation with geolocator API like the following:

```dart
Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

After getting the position, I was planning to set Lat and Long to separate variables for future use.
With a bit of struggle, I finally managed to figure out the right property to get Lat/Long information by type hint from Android Studio.

```dart
...
late double Lat;
late double Long;
...
          Lat = snapshot.data!.latitude;
          Long = snapshot.data!.longitude;
          print("Lat is "+Lat.toString());
          print("Long is "+Long.toString());
```

When typing 'snapshot.data!.', Android Studio shows options available. By looking at property names, I could have guessed which one of these should be the one. However, I don't believe relying on type hint is ideal way to find right property name.

For example, in Javascript, we can console.log() to get detailed information of a specific instance including accessible properties and we can tell property name with actual values at logged.
I tried print() but it doesn't show a property name. (In above case, print(snapshot.data!.toString()) shows {Lat:xxx, Long:xxx}, but actual property names are 'latitude' and 'longitude').

Is there any general way to get detailed information of a specific instance including accessible properties in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally refer to the **API reference** of a package. That is the documentation pages generated by [dartdoc](https://dart.dev/tools/dartdoc).

In your case, this would the [`geolocator` API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator_platform_interface/latest/geolocator_platform_interface/Position-class.html).

See also:

- [Flutter API reference](https://flutter.dart.dev)
- [Dart API reference](https://api.dart.dev)

---

Furthermore, you can use your IDE to view the source code of all members in Dart.

See also:

- [Source code navigation Android Studio / IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#go_to_declaration)
- [Code navigation in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition)